# Blur image on-scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have my container with an image in which when you scroll 50px down the page the image in the container blurs.
Is this possible ( I think I have seen it before but cannot remember where.
The text I want o remain as normal and therefore not blue.

HTML:

```
<div class="hero1">
    <div id="hero1title">
      <h1>simplicity, craft and format <br>is what excites me as a designer</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.hero1{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    background-image: url(../splashscreen.jpg);
    background-color: rgb(247,200,198);
}


div #hero1title h1{
    color: white;
    font-size: 90pt;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 30%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a div which will contain the blur version of your image inside `hero1` or use css to blur it (*see `.hero1 .blur`*) then add the JS code below to create the switching between both images wen scrolling (*run the code snippet at the bottom & go to fullscreen to see how it works*) :

- *Note : Solution inspired from [this codpen.io sample](http://codepen.io/andreasstorm/pen/pyjEh).*

```js
$(window).scroll(function() { 
    // Get scroll position
    var s = $(window).scrollTop(),
    // scroll value and opacity
    opacityVal = (s / 240);
    // opacity value 0% to 100%
    $('.blur').css('opacity', opacityVal);
});
```

```css
 
.hero1{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/1000/600/);
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: rgb(247,200,198);
     
}
.hero1 .blur {
 background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/1000/600/);
 background-size: cover;

 -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
   -moz-filter: blur(10px);
   -o-filter: blur(10px);
   -ms-filter: blur(10px);
   filter: blur(10px);

 height: 100%;
 opacity: 0;
}


div #hero1title h1{
    color: white;
    font-size: 90pt;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 30%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

 <div class="hero1">
    <div class="blur"></div>
    <div id="hero1title">
      <h1>simplicity, craft and format <br>is what excites me as a designer</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Querdani Although the snippet works here, its not working in my website, is there something I am missing?

Comment: @ClarkeCribb that's a **jquery** code so you will need to include the *jquery library* before the JS code in order to work (see my HTML code before closing the *body tag*). 
Also I did add `background-size: cover;` to both `hero1`and `blur` but this is not required, it will depends of your images sizes.

Comment: and of corse the `blur` div inside `hero1` : `<div class="blur"></div>`

Answer (score 0):

This is what I think you were trying to do:

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
    if($(this).scrollTop() >0){
        $('.hero1').css({'webkit-filter':'blur(5px)', 'filter':'blur(5px)'});
    }else{
        $('.hero1').css({'webkit-filter':'', 'filter':''});
    }
});
```

[Here is the **JSfiddle** demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vgw8kzb3/)

Comment: It is however, the text I want to stay the same

Comment: @ClarkeCribb You will have to use a separate _div_ for the text and then have it overlay on top of the _div_ containing the blurred background. Right now your text is within the blurred _div_ and hence it is being blurred as well. As for the '$' not defined, you probably forgot to include JQuery in your html file.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should check this demo:

https://scotch.io/demos/animated-article-headers-blur

Here is a tutorial for this:

https://scotch.io/bar-talk/ideas-and-demos-for-animating-article-headers-on-scroll